# Intercept and indepenent variable's t-value is 0

Tags: regression, mixed-model, categorical-data, repeated-measures, multilevel-analysis

Unfortunately for privacy reasons I cannot disclose the original data <Edited: snippets of the original data below>, but I'm running a regression model like this on R.

```
Call:
lm(formula = Score ~ Agent * Target, data = .)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-3.1997 -0.4643  0.2133  0.6034  2.5762 

Coefficients:
               Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  -7.831e-16  6.930e-02   0.000    1.000    
Agent         2.820e-01  6.949e-02   4.058 6.05e-05 ***
Target        5.863e-16  9.801e-02   0.000    1.000    
Agent:Target  1.094e-01  9.827e-02   1.113    0.266    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.9426 on 366 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.1164,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.1091 
F-statistic: 16.07 on 3 and 366 DF,  p-value: 7.847e-10
```

Both Agent and Target are dummy variables, being 0 and 1, with DV being continuous variable. The variables are standardized. This is actually a repeated measure, meaning one data (one ID) has variables for both when Target = 0 and Target = 1. As you can see,　both intercept and Target showing t-value of 0 and p-value of 1, which makes me suspicious about this analysis. I have checked VIF for multicollinearity, but it seems to be fine (agent and target are dummy variables and should have no correlation anyways).

I have intentionally omitted this analysis in the above for simplicity, but since this is a repeated measure, I also have run mixed-model analysis accounting for ID, which again, shows the same t-value & p-value for intercept and Target.

```
Linear mixed model fit by REML. t-tests use Satterthwaite's method [
lmerModLmerTest]
Formula: Score ~ Agent * Target + (1 | id)
   Data: .

REML criterion at convergence: 880.3

Scaled residuals: 
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-2.79766 -0.43321  0.06451  0.38941  2.29075 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 id       (Intercept) 0.6433   0.8020  
 Residual             0.2452   0.4952  
Number of obs: 370, groups:  id, 185

Fixed effects:
               Estimate Std. Error         df t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)   1.976e-15  6.930e-02  2.401e+02   0.000   1.0000    
Agent         2.820e-01  6.949e-02  2.401e+02   4.058 6.69e-05 ***
Target       -3.975e-16  5.149e-02  1.830e+02   0.000   1.0000    
Agent:Target  1.094e-01  5.163e-02  1.830e+02   2.119   0.0354 *  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) Agent  Target
Agent        0.000              
Target      -0.371  0.000       
Agent:Targt  0.000 -0.371  0.000
```

I have made bunch of different models throwing in a lot more covariates into this model and some other models using diffent DVs or IVs, but still using same Agent + Target + (Agent * Target) IVs, and this pattern of t-value and p-value persist throughout.

If you know any potential issues I would really like to know.
Thank you in advance.

Edit: Added the snippet of the original data for the data structure

```
      id Agent Target Score
   <int> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
 1     1     1      1    71
 2     1     1      0    56
 3     2     1      1    70
 4     2     1      0    58
 5     3     1      1    69
 6     3     1      0    36
 7     4     1      1    52
 8     4     1      0    46
 9     5     1      1    73
10     5     1      0    71
```

There are Scores of Target 0 and Target 1, and they are nested below ID (repeated measures).

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your data structure, it looks to me like you've over-specified your model. I think it should be something like `Score ~ Target + Agent:Target` or `Score ~ Target + Agent*Target - 1`. One of `Agent` or `Target` should be the intercept, but you've specified both of them PLUS intercept in the model. Which in this case is forcing one of them (`Target`) to be close to zero, and thus the p-value to be close to one.

Comment: Thank you for the comment! I'm thinking about overfitting and the models above. I have also added the snippet of my data to give data structure!

Comment: Nah I think this original comment of mine was wrong, upon further thought. It could be: is the t-value 0 because there's actually no difference? e.g. visualise Score on a y axis, and the different 0/1 combinations of Agent & Target on the x

Comment: Actually it seems I have accidenctally standardized the dummy variables as well, which might haved led to weird intercept and t-value...